# Adding custom button in custom table view cell , and at a time only one button of cell should be selected in swift, could anyone help me out for this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, radio-button

Please check out my code of custom UITableview cell, I am facing the problem because tableview delegate did select method is not called.

My Code Here:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DpMarginRptTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None        

    if dataSource.count > 1
    {

        let dpMarginModel : DPSRDPDetailModel = self.dataSource.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! DPSRDPDetailModel
        cell.scriptLabel.text = "\(dpMarginModel.scripCode)"
        cell.dpQtyLabel.text = "\(dpMarginModel.dpBalanceAC)"
        cell.haricutLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f",Float(dpMarginModel.valueAfterHairCut)/100) //"\(dpMarginModel.valueAfterHairCut)"

        cell.transferTextfield.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.transferTextfield.text = "\(dpMarginModel.transferText)"
        cell.transferTextfield.delegate = self
        cell.transferTextfield.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.transferTextfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.radioButton1.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.radioButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DpMarginView.buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.radioButton1.setTitle(String.iconWithName(.radioUnchecked), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.radioButton1.setTitle(String.iconWithName(.radioChecked), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

   }
}
```

**CustomTableViewCell Class** code

```
class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

   var screenWidth:CGFloat!
   var screenHeight:CGFloat!

   var radioButton1 : UIButton!
   var scriptLabel : UILabel!
   var dpQtyLabel:UILabel!
   var haricutLabel:UILabel!
   var transferTextfield: UITextField!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
{
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    self.screenWidth = screenSize.width
    self.screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let boldFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 11)?.fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.TraitBold)

    radioButton1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 5, 30, 40))
    radioButton1.tag = 101
    radioButton1.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Icomoon", size: 18)

    radioButton1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    radioButton1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

    self.scriptLabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(radioButton1.frame.size.width + 5, 5,(screenWidth/4) , 40))
    self.scriptLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    self.scriptLabel.font = UIFont(descriptor: boldFont!, size: 11)



    self.dpQtyLabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(scriptLabel.frame.origin.x + scriptLabel.frame.size.width, 5, (screenWidth/4), 40))
    self.dpQtyLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    self.dpQtyLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 11)


    self.haricutLabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(dpQtyLabel.frame.origin.x + dpQtyLabel.frame.size.width, 5, (screenWidth/4), 40))
    self.haricutLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    self.haricutLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 11)


    self.transferTextfield = UITextField.init(frame: CGRectMake((haricutLabel.frame.origin.x + haricutLabel.frame.size.width)-20, 5, (screenWidth/4) - 20, 40))
    self.transferTextfield.textAlignment = .Center
    self.transferTextfield.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 11)
    self.transferTextfield.keyboardType = .NumberPad

    self.contentView.addSubview(self.radioButton1)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.scriptLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.dpQtyLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.haricutLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.transferTextfield)

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

}

I want to add custom button in custom table view cell, and at a time only one button of cell should be selected in swift, could anyone help me out for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what your cell looks like? Is your problem that `didSelect` doesn't get called or that multiple buttons inside a cell are getting selected?

Comment: If your problem is due to the fact that didselect method is not getting called, then make sure your delegates are conformed and check from storyborad that your selection is set to "single selection" in TableView.

Comment: @Nisha let it also include with your populated tableview screenshot.

Comment: Thank u all i got the solution. I fetched all visible cells of uitableview and deselected all the visible cells.

Answer (score 1):

See this line **cell.radioButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DpMarginView.buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)** shouldn't be there in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Instead you should put that line in **CustomTableViewCell** when you are creating that button. And call that **buttonTapped** action inside CustomTableViewCell itself.

Then you need to use delegate method for passing message form this custom cell to your UIViewVontroller containing this tableview.

So your CustomTableViewCell will start like this:-

```
    protocol CustomDelegate: class {
           func buttonTouchedAction()
        }

    class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

        weak var delegate: CustomDelegate?
        var screenWidth:CGFloat!
        var screenHeight:CGFloat!
        .
        .
        .
}
```

And in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, instead of adding target, use this code:-

```
cell.delegate = self
```

And at the bottom of your viewController add this. I am assuming your viewController name is CustomViewController:-

```
extension CustomViewController: CustomDelegate {
   fun buttonTouchedAction() {
      // Do your action here
   }
}
```

**NB.** Why you are setting the tag as 101 for the radioButton1 in tableViewCell subclass while you are changing it to indexPath.row in viewController's subclass? This entire setting tag thing doesn't serve any purpose here.